# How do I disable java swing menu items?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I used the awt to make a menu and populated that menu with several items.  How do I "disable" the menu items?

Comment: Did you use AWT or Swing? Do all of your component classes start with `J`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
   menuItemInstance.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that was the right the to do, I realized that I was using it in the wrong place. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

can't resist to grumble a bit about the other answers: changing enabled state of the menuItem itself can be done, so they are technically correct. Nevertheless, it's not a good idea most of the time.

Managing enablement state can get quite complex in anything but the most simple environments. Typically, a dedicated state model is needed. Target items of that state model should be data-like (as opposed to view-like). The ideal (because it was designed for it :) target item for menuItems (or other buttons) is the `Action`.

Short version: fill menus with `Action`s and then manage the enablement of the action instead of the component.

Comment: Well it is a simple environment.  I am making a photo editor and I want to disable the menu item if the photo is not there.